# How can I make Loguru log full backtrace to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, stack-trace, loguru

Please excuse if I'm doing something wrong, this is my first question here.

this is my configuration:

```
def logging_module():
    """A customized Loguru logging module"""
    logger.add(sys.stderr, format="{time} {level} {message}", filter="my_module", level="DEBUG")
    logger.add("./logs/log.txt", backtrace=True, diagnose=True, enqueue=True, retention="30 days")
    return logger
```

I'm using the `@logger.catch()` decorator for my whole app.

the problem is the logs in the log.txt file are cut in half [...]. I read the entire API docs and I haven't found a method to change that.

```
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pony\orm\core.py", line 774, in bind
    self._bind(*args, **kwargs)
    │    │      │       └ {'provider': ['provider'], 'user': ['username'], 'password': ['password'], 'database': ['database'], 'host': ['192.168.1....
    │    │      └ ()
    │    └ <function Database._bind at 0x0000021AB8CF3040>
    └ <pony.orm.core.Database object at 0x0000021ACB2269A0>
```

The log in the file looks exactly like this, while I want to know all the **kwargs arguments values in there in my log file.

thanks :)